# mongodb - query embedded document - return only medium screenshots for each software in embedded collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have this simple mongo collection:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4fb176f964debef01e000000"),
  "applicationId": NumberInt(1),
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "caption": "ddd",
      "images": [
        {
          "size": "large",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb176f964debef01e000001"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "medium",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb176f964debef01e000002"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "small",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb176f964debef01e000003"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "caption": "tetsss",
      "images": [
        {
          "size": "large",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb1771164debe9c1a000000"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "medium",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb1771164debe9c1a000001"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        },
        {
          "size": "small",
          "file": {
            "$ref": "File",
            "$id": ObjectId("4fb1771164debe9c1a000002"),
            "$db": "flukeytest"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been reading a lot about the $where function and map reduce but alas I'm not getting very far. I'm trying to select all medium images of every screenshot for one application id. I'm not sure how I can just return the medium image of each screenshot and nothing else. any ideas? Any pointers would be great :)

EDIT: `db.Screenshot.find({ "applicationId": 1, "$where": "function() { return this.screenshots.images.size == 'medium'; }" }).sort([ ]);` I've got this far, but it doesn't work. Alas. Still reading up on everything I can find on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you attempting to return only the medium screenshots? Is it for performance reasons? If there's one document per applicationId, then it won't be much more efficient to return only the medium screenshots (for example, MongoDB will do the same amount of physical IO loading the data from disk). MongoDB is significantly different from a RDBMS in situations like this.

Unless the document in question is huge, and you're trying to return the medium screenshots for many applications in one query, then there won't be much (if any) performance benefit. I would suggest that you just query for the document by applicationId and then filter out the screenshots you want in code.

Eventually, you will probably be able to do this sort of thing using the new [aggregation framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-AggregationFramework), but it won't be released until 2.2.

Comment: Hello. thanks for your answer. i realised this morning how stupid my question was. Yesterday was a long day. thank you.

Comment: Nah. It never hurts to ask. And it's worth confirming that there isn't a huge performance penalty.